# NetBeans, how to set DISPLAY environment for remote SSH server (Pi)

Tags: environment-variables, raspberry-pi3, netbeans-8

I have setup my Pi for SSH remote host development using NetBeans.

I can confirm: in

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10...
```

In addition, xauth is installed on the remote Pi.

I have installed XQuartz on my client mac. Upon ssh -X pi@IPaddress, xquartz opens and if i echo $DISPLAY on the remote Pi i get localhost:12.0 ... the number changes with each terminal.

Currently, if have incorrectly set the project environment in netbeans with:

DISPLAY=localhost:11.0 (this is wrong because the number changes with each ssh connection to the remote Pi).

So when i try to run the program, NetBeans will hang and i cant debug either.

My question is, how do i set the DISPLAY Environment correctly for NetBeans so that each time it makes an SSH connection to the remote Pi and requests X11 forwarding, it will have the correct $DISPLAY?

If I run the program from an SSH -X terminal session to my Pi the program executes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not set `$DISPLAY` yourself, so the first thing to do would be remove it from project variables. Why do you need it there? `ssh` sessions will get `$DISPLAY` set automatically.

Comment: Ok i have removed the DISPLAY environment variable. Closed XQuarts and my terminal ssh -X session. I gies the following output in NetBeans when i try to build and run: `/usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.`

Comment: If i run xquartz then try to run the program in netbeans: `/usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyAutolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.`

Comment: I can see that xquartz isn't starting when i run the program from NetBeans. I have X11 forwarding enabled. This is also set in the remote host properties in the NetBeans Services tab

Comment: if you have the "Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1" error, your have either incorrect `$XAUTHORITY` environment on the pi, or incorrect content in the file pointed to by `$XAUTHORITY`. Why is that I cannot tell. You have a way to establish correct connection to your X server with manual ssh login, use that to debug your Netbeans session and figure out what it does differently and how to fix it.

Comment: I'm struggling to see if there is a way to confirm the SSH log with netbeans and my remote Pi, so far i can't seem to find any ouput logs of the SSH session for running the program. Even though i have selected "Enable X11 forwarding" in the c/c++ build hosts properties menu, xquartz does not start and i receive the x11 initialization failed. Can you advise if there is any way to monitor this in netbeans?

Comment: You can use `ps` or a similar tool to look at the ssh process started by netbeans and its arguments. I'm afraid I don't know anything more.